# Receiving a long value of an operation using two integers (GNU C)

Tags: c, casting, int, overflow, long-integer

Using Microchip C Compiler (based on Gnu C Compiler), I need to process two integer values and return an integer value. Integers are 16 bit wide, longs are 32 bit.

During the calculation, the range of 16bit will be exceeded. This is what I have done so far:

```
unsigned int calcVoltage(unsigned int adcValue){
    long voltage = ((long)adcValue * (long)VOLTAGE) / (long)ADCRANGE;
    return voltage; //12-bit ADC-Value, 3000mv max
}
```

VOLTAGE is a constant, assigned to 3000 at the moment. Multiplying adcValue (0 to 12bit) by 3000 will exceed 16bit. In the end, the result of multiplication will be divided by 4095, so that the result is going to be below 16bit again.

IMO, my code is quite ugly, as I do not know how to do it better. How can I ensure, that the compiler uses 32bit long integers during the calculation without all the explicit casting?

Comment: Setting VOLTAGE as `3000L` instead of `3000` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define VOLTAGE correctly, the rest falls into place because of the usual conversion rules.

```
#define VOLTAGE 3000L

long voltage = (adcValue * VOLTAGE) / ADCRANGE;
```

That's all it takes.

Why, you ask?  Because when the compiler works out how to process the multiplication, it has to multiply a `long` (`VOLTAGE`) by an `int` (`adcValue`), and the way it must do that is by promoting the `int` to a `long`, yielding a `long` result.  When it now evaluates the division, it has a `long` on the LHS (dividend) and an `int` on the RHS (divisor) so it must convert the `int` to a `long` again, do the computation as a `long`, yielding a `long`.  It must then process the assignment.  The LHS is a `long`; the expression on the RHS is a `long`; the world is a happy place (and the code is clean and castless).

Comment: Nice solution (and very good explanation). So if I get this right, the assignment to the variable voltage is done in the end of the processing, and I could also assing the result to an unsigned int?

Comment: Is this the `voltage` or the `VOLTAGE`?  Assuming `voltage` the variable, then the assignment rules change; the `long` would have to be converted to the `unsigned int` type.  The expression wouldn't need to change.  In your context, where the maximum value of `adcValue` is less than or equal to `ADCRANGE`, you should be quite safe, I think.

Comment: Yes, i mean `voltage` which is defined in the function. So for getting this right: The function returns `voltage`as an unsigned int. Using your line of code, the long `voltage` is implicitely converted to an unsigned int when it is returned at the end of the function. If instead the line was `unsigned int voltage = (adcValue * VOLTAGE) / ADCRANGE;`, the result would be the same?

Comment: Yes, and yes. The `long voltage` is already converted to `unsigned int` by the `return` statement; declaring `unsigned int voltage = ...` would do the exact same conversion 'one line earlier' (and not repeat it in the `return`, of course).  So the result would be the same.  You could in theory do without the local variable at all.  I don't recommend that, though; it is hard to debug the return value in a debugger if you write `return (adcValue * VOLTAGE) / ADCRANGE;`.